# What is the iPad's screen size minus the address bar in the browser?

Tags: ipad, browser, cordova, resolution, screen-resolution

What is the browser resolution? I have been searching for a while on google and somehow I can't find it!

Comment: This question has lots of different (and confusing) answers. The best solution seems to be to take a screenshot (press power+sleep button on safari) and measure that. (if it's retina, then divide by 2).

Answer (score 4):

960x768 or 704x1024

Comment: Landscape - 1024(w) x 768(h)
Portrait - 768 (w) x 960 (h)

Answer (score 4):

The below answer is incorrect. The landscape size, after subtracting for UI components which take up space is 981 x 673 (or 644, depending). So your true height is 673(or 644) once you subtract the address bar and status bar.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the screen dimensions, as per my measurements in Photoshop, at least for landscape layouts in Safari:

Screen height: 768px

•  iOS+Safari Chrome: 96px 
  -  Status bar (top black): 20px 
  -  Browser Chrome (Back/FWD Btns, Address Bar, etc.): 44px 
  -  Browser Tab bar: 32px 
•  Web display: 672px

Answer (score 0):

I am working on an application that heavily relies on this exact concept. Our smallest device supported is iPad mini and I got the following width and height configurations working:

```
// iPad mini's browser width and height in portrait
// Needs to subtract toolbar, etc.
const PORTRAIT = {
  width: 744,
  height: 900,
};

// iPad mini's browser width and height in landscape
// Needs to subtract toolbar, etc.
const LANDSCAPE = {
  width: 1024,
  height: 620,
}
```

I tested iPad mini 2019, iPad mini 2021, iPad Air 2019, and iPad Air 4. The configuration seems correct, I based it off on browserstack, and subtracted width and height accordingly.

It is a rough estimate based on the viewport given by browserstack. I needed to decrease width or height as I see fit because in our use case, we show the contents of the app if the screen's size is equal to the iPad mini or above.